# `setuptools_scm` includes a committed `.gitignore` to an `sdist` package

Tags: python, setuptools, pyproject.toml, setuptools-scm

I have a flat-layout project like this:

```
├── project_name
│   └── ...
├── .gitignore
├── pyproject.toml
└── ...
```

I follow [the `setuptools` docs](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/datafiles.html#exclude-package-data) to compose the `pyproject.toml` like this:

```ini
[build-system]
requires = ['setuptools>=45', 'setuptools_scm[toml]>=6.2']

[project]
name = 'project_name'
version = '0.0.1'

[tool.setuptools.exclude-package-data]
"*" = [".gitignore"]
```

However, when I do

```bash
python3 -m build --sdist
```

I get the `.gitignore` file in the resulting `*.tar.gz` file.

I can forcefully exclude the file using a `MANIFEST.in`:

```
exclude .gitignore
```

What the use of the `[tool.setuptools.exclude-package-data]` section, then? Can I do the job without the `MANIFEST.in` file?

Do I misuse the section? From what the building process reports, I guess the `'*'` there means the `project_name` directory. Is there any config key to exclude the `.*` files from the root of the `sdist` package?

---

An MWE for @sinoroc (to be run in a shell):

```bash
# make a dedicated directory and enter it
mkdir package_name
pushd package_name

# make two empty files (only the first one is mandatory)
touch .gitignore README

# fill pyproject.toml
echo "build-system.requires = ['setuptools', 'setuptools_scm[toml]']" >> pyproject.toml
echo "project = {name = 'package_name', version = '0.0.1'}"           >> pyproject.toml
echo "[tool.setuptools_scm]"                                          >> pyproject.toml

# prepare a virtual environment
python -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate
python -m pip install -U pip setuptools build

# commit .gitignore
git init
git add -f .gitignore
git commit -m "add .gitignore"

# build a package
python -m build --sdist

# list the files in the package
tar --list -f dist/package_name-0.0.1.tar.gz

# exit (optional)
deactivate
popd
```

This makes the following file tree:

```
├── .git
│   └── ...
├── dist
│   └── package_name-0.0.1.tar.gz
├── package_name.egg-info
│   └── ...
├── venv
│   └── ...
├── .gitignore
├── pyproject.toml
└── README
```

The `pyproject.toml` file has the following content:

```ini
build-system.requires = ['setuptools', 'setuptools_scm[toml]']
project = {name = 'package_name', version = '0.0.1'}
[tool.setuptools_scm]
```

The `README` and `.gitignore` files are empty. The latter has to be committed for the MWE to work.

It looks that it's the `setuptools_scm` that's to blame for the inclusion of `.gitignore`. The latter should be committed.

Comment: I do not think this should have been closed. Anyway... -- I can not reproduce the issue. I recommend you provide a standalone [mre]. In the question you provided, I can not see any reason why `.github` or `.gitignore` would be included in the *sdist*.

Comment: @sinoroc, "I do not think this should have been closed. Anyway... -- I can not reproduce the issue"—not reproducible is in the list of close reasons. If you can't reproduce it, it _should_ be closed.

Comment: @sinoroc, thanks! I've added an MWE to the question. It isn't a small one, but I can't reduce it much more.

Comment: I see... Seems like it is purely a `setuptools-scm` issue. The [very first section of the doc](https://setuptools-scm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) clearly says to use `MANIFEST.in` to exclude files. What does `ptyhon -m setuptools-scm ls` say? Does it list the files you do not want? -- It seems like normal behavior to me. -- Regarding `exclude-package-data`, as the name says it is for data that is inside an importable package (in a directory with an `__init__.py` file), and also it is meant to exclude files from being installed (i.e. exclude from being added to the wheel, not the sdist).

Comment: Indeed, `python -m setuptools_scm ls` does list `./.gitignore` as a sole file. Thank you so much!